# format rows in google sheets based on conditional range

Tags: google-sheets

I have a data set with 77 rows. One of the columns (let's call it C) contains a name value.  I would like to highlight the row if the name in column C is found in a list of names in another column.

Currently, I'm able to check only a single value, instead of a list of values.  In conditional format rules, I'm able to enter the following formula

```
=$C:$C=$GU$1
```

This, of course, only checks the value against the first name in column GU.  I tried to add :$GU$100 to the condition, but that won't work as the condition is now checking if the entry is the same as the entire value from GU1:GU100.

I thought I might try to use a FIND() method to see if the substring were in the larger string.  To do that, I attempted the following:

```
=$C:$C=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND($C$1,$GU$1:$GU$100)),1,0)
```

While this did not return an error, it also did not highlight any rows.  I'm unsure how to format one row based on whether or not the value in that row is an entry in a list elsewhere.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please select your 'entire row' range (here assumed ColumnsA:G) and Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if..., **Custom formula is**:

```
 =match($C1,$H:$H,0)
```

choose your Formatting style and Done. Where ColumnH is assumed to have your list.

Comment: I tried this and it unfortunately didn't work.  I tried changing the 3rd parameter or omitting it altogether, but still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditional formatting like this with the custom function option and applying to column C, pretending that the list with names your matching against is in column J:

```
=IF(ISTEXT(VLOOKUP(C1:C,J:J,1,false)),TRUE,FALSE)
```